# How can I find a control looking at windows designer in visual studio 2012?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, designer

I have very old code with a lot of controls. On code behind I can find the name of the control. Now I would like easily by it's name find the placement of it on designer view in Visual Studio (or other tool). Is there any possibility to do it?

No list on mine VS:
[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the document outline pane (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) which will include searching a little in the document tree, or the ComboBox in the top of properties pane, which is sorted alphabetically.

[image: Screenshot of ComboBox of properties window, closed and opened]

*Screenshot of ComboBox of properties window, closed and opened*

Comment: I cannot see any ComboBox in VS2012. Can you paste in some screen or clue how to turn it on please?

Comment: Can you look at mine screen please? Why I cannot see it?

Comment: Your screenshot is the **document outline** pane, which does **not** have said ComboBox. The ComboBox is only available in the **Properties** pane (Eigenschaften in my screenshot) - sorry for not clarifying that before

Comment: ok great, isn't there any other better option to search control through some kind of search by its filled in name?

Answer (score 9):

not sure if this was what you wanted, and I realise that its an old post BUT:

1 Click on the Form(design) so that you can see your form and the controls.

2 Then click on Properties and just under the Properties title bar you will see a drop-down box. (if you cant see properties then F4)

3 It has a list of all the controls on the form and when you select one, it will take you to that control on the form.

Comment: The third option helped me find what i wanted, thank you!