# How can I find a button by name in designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm working with a legacy VB.NET, Windows Forms application in Visual Studio that has dialogs with several buttons.

I can't find the specific button I'm looking for on the designer canvas.

Is there a shortcut that lets you search for a button on the designer canvas by name?

Comment: You can use the Document Outline window to select any control and you also have a drop-down list at the top of the Properties window.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Great suggestions. The Document Outline window rings a bell, but I don't recall when I last used it - the Properties Window being my reflex I guess. Taking a look at the Document Outline window, I especially like how it shows the hierarchical relationships between controls in the form: bonus.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The Document Outline window is a neat window I did know about.  Unfortunately, it does not alphabetize items.  My form has over 100 widgets with no hierarchical relationships so it's still a bit difficult to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find a control looking at windows designer in visual studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451439/how-can-i-find-a-control-looking-at-windows-designer-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First Thought

You can use Visual Studio's Properties Window in design view to choose controls on the form by name:

[image: Visual Studio's Properties Window in Design View]

If your Properties Window is not displayed already, you can open it through the View menu (*View > Properties Window*) or by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>.  The above screenshot is from VS 2013; but the Properties Window has been in VS for many versions.

### Afterthought

You can also tab through controls in design view by selecting one

[image: Tabbing Through WinForms Controls in Visual Studio's Design View 01]

then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to shift focus to the next one

[image: Tabbing Through WinForms Controls in Visual Studio's Design View 02]

and pressing it again to advance to the next one

[image: Tabbing Through WinForms Controls in Visual Studio's Design View]

etcetera.

This is not a shortcut to locate a control on the design canvas by name per se; but it is handy for the situation you describe; and you will notice that the current-control name in the Properties Window changes with the shift in focus each time you press Tab (which does more specifically fit your desire to find a control by name).

Comment: Thanks.  Selecting the item from the properties window also selected it on the canvas, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect, saved me a ton of time on an inherited codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Document Outline**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w) which will show you every object on the Form and automatically locate it wherever it is.

1. Go to View > Other Windows > Document Outline or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

   [image: Document Outline]
2. Navigate the Tree and find the Object you want

   [image: Navigate Tree]

Answer (score -1):

Since personally I didn't understand what people were talking about at first,

Here's a quick gif of what to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnfvN.gif